# How I can displace header of data in python.pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem with opening a .prn file using pandas. My file contains spaces at the end of lines which causes a shift in the headers. Below is an example of what I need. How can I get the behaviour I want?

```py
    import pandas as pd
    filename='D:/EXP/7head+2cup 60kHz/k=15 I=80 mA 20 kg/1p.prn'
    df=pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', header=[0])
    a = list(df['Temp'])
    print(df)
    print(a)
```

Input:
[image: Result of print data]

Expected output:

[image: correct answer]

Comment: `pd.read_csv(skiprows=...)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang, no, i tried, but it doesn't work.

Comment: what you need is the `index_col` parameter. try `pd.read_csv(...,index_col = False)` This forces  pandas to not use the first column as the index

Comment: @Onyambu I tried, but the result is no changes (picture is "input")

Comment: @Alex you tried `False`?

Comment: @Onyambu if i tried "false": index_col must only contain row numbers when specifying a multi-index header